# Accidentally deleted .bashrc file in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I just installed Ubuntu and accidentally deleted .bashrc file in Ubuntu 11.04

Is there a way to recover it or a default one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default files put in a home directory on creation are in `/etc/skel`.